# uploading tracks for playback into multritrack recorder?+

Tags: recording, homerecording, multitrack

I got a Zoom R16 recorder so i can collaborate with long distance band members. They recorded their parts and then sent me the files over email so I can record my tracks, But i cant figure out how to load the file into my recorder so i can playback tracks and record my tracks. The Zoom R16 manual lists 2 way to do this: 1) Plug the R16 to a computer as a STORAGE device, and 2) plug in the SD card into the computer. When I tried the methods described in the R16 manual #1, my computer (Macbook) did not recognized the R16 at all. The R16 turned on and it defaulted itself to USB STORAGE but it would not show up on my desktop. When I tried #2 and copy the WAV files into the SD cards, the R16 could not see them, the R16 interface to browse the SD card was not straightforward. What am I doing wrong? What thins should I look for? Are there other ways to do this?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Zoom's feature page for the R16 Recorder](https://www.zoom-na.com/products/production-recording/multi-track-recorders/zoom-r16-recorder-interface-controller#features), there are two ways you could do it:

1. The R16 connect to your computer through a USB interface, and it can function as a mass storage device.  That means that you can copy (or drag-and-drop) files onto it.
2. The R16 records on SD and SDHC cards.  These are removable; most computers these days have a slot that you can plug the card into.

In most cases it will be faster to write directly on the SD card, but there may not be enough of a difference to be worthwhile.  In either case, you'll want to check your manual for the right filenames and extensions to use for the track you're copying.

Comment: When I tried #1, my computer (Macbook) did not recognized the R16 at all. The R16 turned on and it defaulted itself to USB STORAGE but it would not show up on my desktop.  When I tried #2 and copy the WAV files into the SD cards, the R16 could not see them, the R16 interface to browse the SD card was not straight forward.